# PHP webservice results and array

Tags: php, arrays, web-services

I'm still having problems with arrays, I don't know why ...
I'm getting response from web services with a number of room (0,1,2,3,4,5,...) and a renting value associated.
I will then need to do some calculation (average) per number of room.

So I thought that an array would be best.

But I'm struggling to create the array or arrays and populate it/them ...

Thanks in advance.

The code is:

```
    // if the search is buy then search for rent as well to have an estimate value
    if ($_POST['ListingType'] == 'buy'){
        // Initialise the array
        $estimate = array();
        $estimate['requestCountry']    = 'UK';
        $estimate['requestEncoding']   = 'json';
        $estimate['searchPlaceName']   = $_POST['Location'];
        $estimate['filterListingType'] = 'rent';
        if(isset($_POST['PropertyType'])) 
            $estimate['filterPropertyType'] = $_POST['PropertyType'];
        else
            $estimate['filterPropertyType'] = 'all';
        if(isset($_POST['PriceMax']))
            $estimate['filterPriceMax']    = $_POST['PriceMax'];
        else
            $estimate['filterPriceMax']    = 'max';
        if(isset($_POST['PriceMin']))
            $estimate['filterPriceMin']    = $_POST['PriceMin'];
        else
            $estimate['filterPriceMin']    = 'min';
        if(isset($_POST['roomMax']))    
            $estimate['filterBedroomMax'] = $_POST['roomMax'];
        else
            $estimate['filterBedroomMax'] = 'max';
        if(isset($_POST['roomMin']))    
            $estimate['filterBedroomMin'] = $_POST['roomMin'];
        else
            $estimate['filterBedroomMin'] = 'min';
        $nestoriaEstimate = new Nestoria_Nestoria($estimate);
        //print_r( $nestoriaEstimate->decodedData);
        if (!empty($nestoriaEstimate->decodedData->response)) {
            $idxEst=0;
            $rentEst = array();
            foreach($nestoriaEstimate->decodedData->response->listings as $listingEst) {                
                switch ($listingEst->bedroom_number) {
                    echo '<div>Rent' . $listingEst->price_formatted . '<br/>Bedroom(s)' . $listingEst->bedroom_number . '</div>';
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

Which will display:

Rent450 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)1
Rent295 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)1
Rent545 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)2
Rent650 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)2
Rent395 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)1
Rent425 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)1
Rent500 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)1
Rent995 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)2
Rent395 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)1
Rent535 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)1
Rent695 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)2
Rent450 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)2
Rent475 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)2
Rent375 GBP per month
Bedroom(s)1

Comment: are we missing half the question? This seems like a rant...

Comment: It would help if we could see a. your code b. the response from the web service.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: I've edited my post with the code and results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single dimensional arrays basically work as follows:

You have a key/value pair for each "entry" in the array.

an example would be:

```
 0 - Dog
 1 - Cat
 2 - Mouse
```

Notice that by default the first index (key) is 0.

You can obtain the value associated with the key by inserting the key into the brackets for the array variable.

ex:

```
echo $myArray[1];
// this would yield Cat
```

there is also an array type called an associative array in which case the indices are not numeric, but rather have  textual representation (string).

an example would be:

```
 pet - dog
 job - programmer
 hobby - kite flying
```

so to pull a value out of an array like this, you would just use the textual representation in the brackets

ex:

```
echo $myArray["pet"];
// would yield dog
```

for your purposes, since the service is returning a 0 based list, you should use numeric indices as I showed above.  to add new key/value pairs to your array, you can loop over the result set and do something like this:

```
$myArray[] = $myValue;
```

where each iteration of the loop will add the new key/value pair (just incrementing the keys from 0).

EDIT (per your comment):

to loop over an array you can use a for loop or a foreach loop.

foreach example:

```
$studio = Array(200,250,240,150);
foreach($studio as $key => $val)
    echo $studio[$key]."<br />";
```

Comment: Christopher, thanks for your summary. But I'm still confused, maybe because it's late... What I was thinking was to have an array 'studio', where I would have the rent $studio[200,250,240,150], one for a one bedroom house/flat $oneBed[300,350], ... But I have problem looping and assigning values to the different arrays.

Comment: Thanks Christopher. I'm sorry, I think I'm not expressing myself very well! How do I put those values within the arrays? Lets take 3 results , number of rooms / rent: 1 - 250, 3 - 500, 1 - 225. I would like to have $onebed['250','200'] and $threebed['225'].

Comment: sorry but your questions aren't making much sense.  If you want to have separate key/value pairs nested within the array, you'll need to use a multidimensional array.  If I understand what you're trying to do (and I more than likely don't as you haven't explained yourself very well), you'd probably be better off using objects as they can contain and represent data that's much more easily accessible than arrays can.

Comment: OK, got it... and I'm going to bed! To assign a value you do as you said: $myArray[] = $myValue; THANK YOU CHRISTOPHER.